# Does serviceworker.js need to load from the root

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am using the [progressive web app module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pwa/releases/7.x-1.x-dev) from Drupal and it loads the file from /pwa/serviceworker.js

Reading this article it says you need to load the Service worker from root https://frustrated.blog/2016/07/17/pwa_step_one.html and 
https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox/issues/158

Can I load the service worker from anywhere? say modules/pwa/js/serviceworker.js ?

It seems to be working that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you load a service worker in /modules/pwa/js, it can only manage resources under this path. So, you have to place your SW at the root of your public path. A solution is to use url rewrite with an htaccess file for example.